# ListBox not showing items horizontally after using theme

Tags: wpf

I am using a listbox as my Menu items holder, by using

```
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                <ItemsPanelTemplate>

                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />

                    <WrapPanel></WrapPanel>

                </ItemsPanelTemplate>

            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

i can show all my items horizontally in listbox but whenever i use any theme it started showing items vertically (I am using Microsoft's ExpressionLight.xaml in my project's Application.xaml)

Any solution, even if how to stop my listbox (only this one) using theme.

Regards,

Answer (score 8):

We had the same problem with ExpressionDark and discovered it was a problem in the Style.

To fix simply modify the ListBox ControlTemplate (Line 710 in ExpressionDark.xaml for us):

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Grid>
        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2" Background="{DynamicResource ControlBackgroundBrush}" />
        <ScrollViewer Margin="1" Style="{DynamicResource NuclearScrollViewer}" Focusable="false" Background="{x:Null}">
            <StackPanel Margin="1,1,1,1" IsItemsHost="true" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
    ...
```

Change the StackPanel to an ItemsPresenter:

```
<ItemsPresenter Margin="1,1,1,1"/>
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: Just had the exact same problem - it took a while to figure out that the Theme was the problem! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess the theme has a default setting for orientation which overwrites your settings?

Comment: if it is so how can we stop only this listbox (Menu item holder) to stop using theme.

Comment: There are 2 things I'd try, first to generate a default style template with Expression Blend and see if that breaks your ListBox (to see if it's the theme), then see if the theme is meddling with the ItemsPanelTemplate, you might be able to override just that with a custom template resource.

Comment: got solution from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/92e159fa-1bae-46be-950a-9cd90355340b